# anova() function for mixed effect models in lmer gives wrong output

Tags: r, lme4, anova, mixed-models

I'm comparing two mixed effects models to each other.

```
mod_1 <- lmer(firstfix ~ ps + cd + ps:cd + (1+ cd||subj) + (1+ ps||object), data = dat2, REML = FALSE)

mod_2 <- lmer(firstfix ~ ps  + ps:cd + (1+ cd||subj) + (1+ ps||object), data = dat2, REML = FALSE)

anova(mod_1, mod_2)
```

But the output of the anova() function is wrong. It looks like: [image]

The individual models give the correct output, so I'm not sure why the anova() function is being difficult? Thankful for any advice on what may be causing this or how to fix it.

Comment: Please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example-aka-mcve-minimal-complete-and-ver). Also please include the output as text, not as a picture. What was the expected output?

Comment: Have you somehow overwritten the anova function? (ie to reproduce try `summary(anova(almerModel))`). Does the error persist after restarting R? Does it work if you call the method explicitly `lme4:::anova.merMod(mod_1, mod_2)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I **strongly** suspect that you typed `summary(anova(mod_1,mod_2))` rather than just `anova(mod_1,mod_2)`. I can get very similar output via

```
library(lme4)
mod_1 <- lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject),sleepstudy)
mod_2 <- lmer(Reaction~1+(Days|Subject),sleepstudy)
summary(anova(mod_1,mod_2))
```

whereas `anova(mod_1,mod_2)` is fine.

Answer (score -1):

You could try by coding your interaction using a * rather than the semicolon when fitting the models :

> lmer(firstfix ~ ps + ps*cd + (1+ cd||subj) + (1+ ps||object), data = dat2, REML = FALSE)

Comment: this is unlikely to be the issue.  (Not downvoting, yet, as I guess there's a tiny chance that it's relevant.)

Comment: I believe you're right and that is irrelevant. Other thing I can think of is storing the anova before running it :
> anova -> anova (...) 
And then you should more easily access it from your global environment